# Mac OS X Terminal.app — automatically setup Home/End/Page Up/Down keys

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

We [know](https://superuser.com/questions/100992/mousing-and-page-up-down-in-terminal-for-mac-os-x) how to setup Home/End/Page Up/Down keys in Terminal.app using interface, but does anybody know how make it automatically (maybe shell script, or apple script) so you don't need to go again through interface options when switching to another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy the preferences file from one machine to the other. It's at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` You can `scp` it, email it, or copy it to a flash drive—whatever works :)

That should copy all of your Terminal preferences, including things like other key bindings and themes.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a script or [PlistBuddy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) to edit the `keyMapBoundKeys` dictionaries in `com.apple.Terminal.plist`. It can be converted from binary to XML with `plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can export settings profiles (each item in the Settings list is a “settings profile” or “profile”), then import them on the other machine.

To export, you can drag a profile out of the list into Finder. To import, just open the resulting *.terminal file. There are also explicit import/export commands in the action (gear) menu at the bottom of the profile list, and you can drag these files into the list, as well.